# ¿Me pueden ayudar a encontrar el error? ciclo repetitivo for C++

Tags: c, algoritmos, ciclos

Tengo que imprimir el promedio de las notas aprobadas y el promedio de las notas aprobadas pero me sale mal.

¿Alguno tiene alguna sugerencia?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main () {

    int proma=0,promd=0,n,sumap=0,suman=0,contador=0,contadorp=0,contadorn=0;
    printf("Ingrese las 10 notas:\n");

    for(contador=1;contador<=10;contador++){

        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n>=6) {
          contadorp++;
          sumap=sumap+n;
          proma=sumap/contadorp;
        }
        else if(n<6)
           contadorn++;
           suman=suman+n;
          promd=suman/contadorn;
    }

    printf("\nEl promedio de las notas aprobadas es de: %d ",proma);
    printf("\nEl promedio de las notas desaprobadas es de: %d",promd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

especifica que error es?

fijándome por el código el error sería que te faltan dos { }

```
else if(n<6){

contadorn++;

suman=suman+n;

promd=suman/contadorn;}
```

Comment: si, creo que no tenia ningun error y si lo quiero hacer con n numeros, osea que no me den la cantidad de notas como tendria que hacer?

Comment: Bueno, podrias crear una variable llamada tam, y darle un valor por consola antes de entrar al ciclo for.

`int tam = 10;
printf ("Digite la cantidad de notas: ");
scanf ("%d",&tam);
 for(contador=1;contador<=tam;contador++){`

Answer (score 3):

El error es de sintaxis a simple vista. Ya que una estructura lleva más de una línea de código interna se debe añadir las `{ ...}` que es lo que le falta en el `else if`

Propondré una solución con algunas modificaciones :

- El tipo de la variable promedio no debería ser un entero si no un `float` *para que tome en cuenta los decimales*
- Otro *error*  lógico de la comparación adicional en el segundo `if` , donde podría haber sido un `else` así se evitaba la comparación adicional dado que la única otra opción del `if` es que sea `< 6`
- Si tiene variables acumuladoras como la suma y variables contadoras de las notas no es necesario hacer la operación de promedio en cada Iteración. si no más bien al final del ciclo.
- Lo lógico sería que utilizara una variable para la cantidad de notas ingresadas.una variable adicional `nottotal`;
- La impresión de la variable `float` la realizo con `%.2f`que representa dos decimales.

El Código quedaría :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main () {
    int n,sumap=0,suman=0,contadorp=0,contadorn=0, nottotal;
    float proma=0,promd=0;
    printf("Ingrese cantidad de notas:\n");
    scanf("%d",&nottotal);
    printf("Ingrese Notas :\n");
    for(int contador=0;contador<nottotal;contador++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n>=6) {
           contadorp++;
           sumap=sumap+n;
        }
        else{
          contadorn++;
          suman=suman+n;
      }
    }
  proma = (float)sumap/contadorp;
  promd = (float)suman/contadorn;
  printf("\nEl promedio de las notas aprobadas es de: %.2f ",proma);
  printf("\nEl promedio de las notas desaprobadas es de: %.2f",promd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione, simplemente tienes que coger estas dos líneas:

```
proma = sumap/contadorp;
promd = suman/contadorn;
```

sacarlas fuera del bucle `for` y ponerlas justo antes de los `printf` finales. Esto es debido a que las medias debes calcularlas una vez tenga la suma total de notas y el número de notas, tanto aprobadas como suspendidas.

Además, si permites que el promedio sea un número decimal, las variables promedio deben ser un `float` y hacer la división de manera que si la suma y el contador son enteros, convertirlos a `float` (casting o *1.0).